# How to Generate RSA Keys in VSS verifone and compute public /CA?

Tags: verifone

I am not able to generate RSA key pair inside VSS through macros. I am in need of script to gerate key inside and compute Public CA and do RSA computation inside. Please help in this regard.

Comment: VSS?  I'm not familiar with that acronym...  Is CommServer (VCS) an option?

Comment: VSS-VeriFone Security Script ..this module is used for key management and computation .

Comment: Oh, so is this like for injecting keys into pin pads and such?  I'm afraid you're out of my realm... :)

Comment: Yes, this is used for key injection in terminal secure slots. abc.vss file get compiled to abc.vso file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to generate a RSA keypair inside VSS (v4.0).

You might want to try generating a keypair using the embedded openssl and then store it into the key slot (beware that there are probably some constraints on some key slots (modulus length,exponent length) -- check your documentation).

Beware that the `RSACOMP` operation does only a raw RSA computation (modular exponentiation) and you will have to handle the padding stuff yourself (and correctly).

---

A much simpler alternative is to generate the keypair outside (HSM?) and inject it securely to the terminal (I do not understand your use case -- but some certificate for this keypair could be injected as well)

Good luck!